# glEnableClientState and glDisableClientState of OpenGL

Tags: opengl

What is the meaning of `glEnableClientState` and `glDisableClientState` in OpenGL?
So far I've found that these functions are to enable or disable some client side capabilities.

Well, what exactly is the client or server here?
I am running my OpenGL program on a PC, so what is this referring to?
Why do we even need to disable certain capabilities? ...and more intriguing it's about some sort of an array related thing?

The whole picture is very gray to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original terminology stems from the X11 notation, where the server is the actual graphics display system:

- A server program providing access to some kind of display device

and

- Clients connecting to the server to draw on the display device provided by it

`glEnableClientState` and `glDisableClientState` set state of the client side part. Vertex Arrays used to be located in the client process memory, so drawing using vertex arrays was a client local process.

Today we have Buffer Objects, that place the data in server memory, rendering the whole client side terminology of vertex arrays counterintuitive. It would make sense to discard client states and enable/disable vertex arrays through the usual `glEnable`/`glDisable` functions, like we do with framebuffer objects and textures.

Comment: Good answer, more precise than mine. By the way, as fixed semantic vertex arrays are deprecated and the generic ones use `gl[En/Dis]ableVertexAttribArray`, the client state functions are deprecated anyway. So the semantic conflict isn't that much of a problem anymore (at least in the future).

Comment: Now, should I avoid using Vertex array? and this client server mechanism?

Comment: @iamcreasy: In the contrary! If you really need high performance, Vertex Arrays are the only way to go. Please don't fall for the same misconception, that a server/client mechanism would mean loss in performance; a lot of people think X11 was slow for that it is a client/server mechanism. However I repeatedly found well written X11 programs to outperform their Windows and MacOS X counterparts, sometimes by severals orders of magnitude.

Comment: okey, that's why gl[En/Dis]ableVertexAttribArray was introduced? right? I just should avoid the old commands then. just the  gl[En/Dis]ableClientState part. Right?

Comment: @iamcreasy: Don't be fooled by the naming of the functions gl{En,Dis}ableClientState is no more expensive than gl{En,Dis}ableVertexAttribArray if applied on VBOs. And please keep in mind that Client/Server doesn't necesarily mean any impacts on bandwidth. On a modern operating system, writing to a loopback socket (i.e. communicating with 127.0.0.1) has almost no overhead: The networking stack just sets the pages sent to COW and then only a pointer is passed within the network stack. The net effect is, that loopback sockets turn into shared memory!

Answer (score 7):

If you draw your graphics by passing buffers to OpenGL (glVertexPointer(), etc) instead of direct calls (glVertex3f()), you need to tell OpenGL which buffers to use.

So instead of calling glVertex and glNormal, you'd create buffers, bind them, and use glVertexPointer and glNormalPointer to point OpenGL at your data. Afterwards a call to glDrawElements (or the like) will use those buffers to do the drawing. However, one other required step is to tell the OpenGL driver which buffers you actually want to use, which is there glEnableClientState() comes in.

This is all very hand-wavy. You need to read up on vertex buffer objects and try them out.

Comment: You don't need buffers to use vertex arrays. Actually the "client state" semantic was developed long before buffers and doesn't make much sense in connection with buffers, as these are controlled by the driver and not the client.

Comment: to me @chris-mennie's made sense according to [this tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html), but, @christian-rau sorry, i didn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: So far it feels to me, that because OpenGL is a state mechine, it requires certain set of masking to determine what to do with the incoming data. That's why it requires to enable and disable some stuff. But, I dont understand, why you need to enable and disable cpu/driver side operation to go for vertex array operation? or am i mistaken completely?

Comment: @iamcreasy, Christian's talking about the fact that, unless you're using core OpenGL 3.2 or above (which is what that tutorial was written for), you don't have to use buffer objects for your vertex arrays. You can use memory that you allocate normally on the CPU. Indeed, that's why the OpenGL functions are called glVertex*Pointer*; because they used to only take pointers. The functions were later overloaded to take buffer object offsets.

Comment: @iamcrasy, the reason you need to enable/disable arrays is because there is no other way to say, "I was using this array before but I don't want to do so anymore". OpenGL is a state machine, so it preserves all state in the form you last left it in. You can't use glColorPointer to say, "Don't fetch data for this color." So instead, you use glEnable/DisableClientState to tell OpenGL which arrays to pull from and which not to.

Comment: From your first comment, I guess I can conclude that what @chris-mennie said is correct. Your second comment is a little over my head. I'm going to start reading your tutorials! :) One more thing, is there anything in your tutorial that is obsolete?

Comment: If you're asking if my tutorials use anything that was deprecated in 3.0 and removed in 3.1, the answer is no.

Comment: @iamcreasy Look at my answer and my comment on this answer for more insight into the motivation for the term "client state". What Chris said is indeed correct but doesn't really explain why the array state is client state and what client and server state really mean.

Comment: @nicol-bolas is it a good idea to stop using those that are deprecated or removed in OGL 4 or greater? or when Im learning OGL 3 or greater, I should follow their tradition.

Comment: @iamcreasy OpenGL is not like D3D, where they go through radical API shifts at every major version. Even D3D isn't like that anymore, with D3D11 being quite close to D3D10. OpenGL 4.0 removes nothing from OpenGL 3.3. The only removal happened at the 3.0 to 3.1 boundary; ever since then, it has only been additions. So if you write to 3.3 core, it will run on 4.0 core. Or 4.1 core.

Answer (score 4):

In OpenGL terminology, the client is your application, whereas the server is the graphics card (or the driver), I think. The only client-side capabilities are the vertex arrays, as these are stored in CPU memory and therefore on the client-side or more specifically, they are controlled (allocated and freed) by your application and not by the driver.

Vertex buffer objects are a different story. They can be used as vertex arrays, but are controlled by the driver, so the word "client state" doesn't make  so much sense anymore when working with buffers.

Answer (score 2):

`glEnableClientState` and `glDisableClientState` are mainly used to manage [Vertex Arrays](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Arrays) and [Vertex Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO).